# Unity InputField onSubmit, C#, changing normalColor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to change my input field's normalColor when user is done editing it, I already have the code, but wasn´t able to make it work with unity¨s onSubmit method. I want to run my code once user stops editing the input field.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the LostFocus event for this capability.